# Why respond_to with initialize() returns false?

Tags: ruby, class

Why do I get false when I do  `C.respond_to?(:initialize)`

```
class C
  def initialize;end
  def meth;end
end

C.respond_to?(:initialize) #=> false
C.new.respond_to?(:meth) #=> true as expected
```

Another variation

```
class C
  def initialize;end

  def meth
    pmeth
  end

  private

  def pmeth
    respond_to?(:initialize)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `#initialize` is not public method. If you want to check private,protected methods by using [**`#respond_to?`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F), set the second parameter as `true`.

**Documentation clearly saying**

> Returns true if obj responds to the given method. Private and protected methods are included in the search only if the optional second parameter evaluates to true.

See below:

```
class C
  def initialize;end
  def meth;end
end

C.respond_to?(:initialize,true)
# => true
C.new.respond_to?(:initialize)
# => false
C.new.respond_to?(:initialize,true)
# => true
C.private_methods(false).include?(:initialize) # => true
C.new.private_methods(false).include?(:initialize) # => true
```